# How do I define the character of a string as an "index" to then calculate character frequency in both directions?

Tags: python, pandas, string, matplotlib, indexing

This question will apply to a bigger function I am creating to calculate the frequency of characters in a string using different starting positions in that string. For example, here are two example strings, but my data includes thousands.

```
protein=TTTRSKYYYEEERSKQQQ
peptide1 = TTTRSKYYY
peptide2 = EEERSKQQQ
```

I understand how to count the frequency of characters in a string, but what if I wanted to use the character S as the starting position [0] to then assign positional frequencies of characters in both directions to calculate the combined frequency of characters (i.e. average between peptide 1 and peptide 2). I would need to split a string (protein) based on the occurrence of (S).

The expected output would be a frequency of 100% for R and K at position -1 and +1 respectively, whereas the other characters (T,E,Y,Q) would produce a frequency 50% at the specified positions relative to "S".

```
where character in protein is "S":
       peptide= # of characters before and after "S
       count frequency of characters at each index.
```

Any insight on where to start would be great, I am willing to test and adapt, but mostly looking for a place to start. I was thinking of creating a dictionary for each peptide then building a dataframe before I use matplotlib to produce a visual.

Comment: This was hard to describe so I am happy to clarify in the comments.

Comment: You could use a dictionary whose indexes are tuples `(character, offset)` where `offset` is the difference between the character's index and the `S` index.

Comment: You can also turn each string into a list of tuples like that, concatenate them, and then use `collections.Counter()` to get the frequency of each tuple.

Comment: @Barmar I have not used either of those features in Python. I will test it a bit and see how it works out. For turning the string into a list of tuples, how would I define were to create a smaller string (peptide) from the larger string (protein). I am unsure of how to use character indexing to automate this process.

Comment: `spos1 = peptide1.index("s"); list1 = [(char, i - spos1) for i, char in enumerate(peptide1)]`

Comment: Beautiful. That makes sense. I will play around with it and post an example when I get it to work.